# Rehashing method throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, hash, overflow

I'm trying to do a method that automatically creates a new hashTable with 1.25 more capacity, but I have a overflow error. The code is:

```
public void reHash (){

    Config.MAX_ESTACIONS = (int) (Config.MAX_ESTACIONS * 1.25);
    Vector<EstacioHash>[] newHashTable = new Vector[Config.MAX_ESTACIONS];

    EstacioHash nouElement = new EstacioHash();

    for (int i=0; i<hashTable.length;i++){
        for (int k=0; k<hashTable[i].size();k++){

            nouElement.key = hashTable[i].get(k).key;
            nouElement.value = hashTable[i].get(k).value;

            int position = hashFunction(nouElement.key);
            newHashTable[position].add(nouElement); <---- OverFlow here
        }
    }

    hashTable = newHashTable;

}
```

Why I have an overFlow? The programs run correctly without the rehash function. The hash function is:

```
public int hashFunction (Object clau){

    String clauMinuscules = ((String) clau).toLowerCase(); 

    char[] key = clauMinuscules.toCharArray(); 
    int result=0;

    for (int i=0;i<key.length;i++){
        result = (result + key[i]^i)%Config.MAX_ESTACIONS;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have an overflow but more a `NullPointerException`.

The default value for an `Object` is `null`. When creating the new table, you have an array full of `null` values.

You need to initialize each entry of the `newHashTable` before trying to get the `Vector` at some position and add something into it.

```
Vector<EstacioHash>[] newHashTable = new Vector[Config.MAX_ESTACIONS];
for (int i=0; i<newHashTable.length;i++){
    newHashTable[i] = new Vector<EstacioHash>();
}
```

Comment: The problem that I have now is the first time I use the reHash method if works perfect. The second and third time it doesn't work good. All the values goes to the same position of the hashTable. Why this happens?

Comment: @user2911701 You're saying that all the elements are adding to the same vector? Maybe your hashFunction doesn't work as expected. Also note that you are always adding the same reference in your table. You should put `EstacioHash nouElement = new EstacioHash();` inside the nested loop.